# Changing url of html pages

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to change the url of my html page to as below

1. **example.com/intraday.html**    to example.com/intraday.
2. **example.com/economic_calendar.html** to **example.com/economiccalendar**

I am trying it using .htaccess file but it is not working

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^\ ]+)\.html
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L]
```

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2.html [L]
```

Comment: I added this code in my .htaccess file. After that when I type example.com/intraday. It says 404. Do I need to wait for sometime or there is some issue

Comment: hi, please try updated code one, it will on root level.

Comment: still no help, I even tried specific for godaddy server.